# Qt- How to Draw Text from a QListWidget

Tags: scroll, qwidget, qt4.7, qlistwidget

Am Learning to do something with QListWidget. I have a **QListWidget, QTextEdit , 2 QPushButtons** (Add & Remove Buttons) and **a QWidget** for drawing the Text in it. When i *enter a text in the QTextEdit and Click's the Add Button, the text has to add in the QListWidget*. And from that QListWidget, *i select any item and click's the Remove Button, the item has to be removed from the QListWidget*. ***Then i want to draw this QListWidget Items in the QWidget and this drawed items has to scroll from Right to left.*** How can i do this? Plz help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//In the constructor
WidgetString = "";

On_add_button_Clicked() //SLOT
{
 listwidget->addItem(lineedit->text());

}

On_Remove_Button_clicked() //SLOT
{
 listWidget->takeItem(listWidget->currentIndex());
 //You may have to delete the the item taken in order to put that change into effect.
 //Trigger paintevent
}

on_listWidget_currentTextChanged(QString currentText) //SLOT
{
 WidgetString = currentText;
}

paintevent()
{
 QPainter painter(Your_Qwidget);
 painter.drawText ( int xPos, int YPos, WidgetString )
 update();
}
```

For the Scrollbar thing, you may need to increase the Text size you are going to Draw.